# Ubuntu installer not able to detect my SSD

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb, ssd

I am trying to install ubuntu as a second operating system and would like to run it as dual boot. I am not able to install ubuntu into my laptop as I am not able to see my SSD in the installation process.

Comment: is your system have only one drive that is this SSD? do you have your windows on it?

Comment: I believe to remember that happening to me too:  1st time I used an ssd I needed to create a Ubuntu EFI partition * from the BIOS* and then tell it from inside the BIOS to boot from it.

Comment: @PRATAP i have windows installed in it . It was preinstalled by my laptop manufacturer HP.

Comment: @Rinzwind how would I do that.  How would I create an Ubuntu EFI partition from the bios.

Comment: @crazyCoder can you open diskmgmt.msc from windows10 and share the pic

Comment: If you have windows already on it there is no need. Mine was an empty unformatted ssd. Windows install already made it EFI. If so: you probably need to boot from BIOS with the option USB UEFI.

Comment: @Rinzwind I did boot from usb. But after booting from usb, I am unable to find out my ssd on the steps.

Comment: That's not what I said: boot from INSIDE BIOS using the boot override order setting picking USB UEFI.

Comment: I am not able to do anything. I did boot using the USB UEFI using boot override.  @Rinzwind